# Setting baseUrl for Axios in Vue js sends out request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

In my app I use Axios to handle my API-requests. In main.js I have set the baseUrl. Without me making a request it makes a request on its own just by setting the baseUrl, so always when the app is loaded in the browser.

In my main.js `axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://domain.nl/path/to/my/api`

All works fine but a request to the baseUrl gives back a 500 for not requesting data.

The implementation in main.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
```

config:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = https://domain.nl/path/to/my/api
axios({
withCredentials: true,
credentials: 'same-origin',
headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }})
```

Then in another file I do an `export default {}` which contains:

```
getLang(payload) {

    payload.method = 'GET'
    payload.url = 'lang';

    return axios(payload).then(result => {
        return result.data
    });
}
```

Does anyone know how to cancel this request or is there a better way to set the baseUrl without this 'bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to replicate your problem but it works fine to me, how are you implementing Axios? Which version are you using?

**[EDIT] Suggested solution**

Using this as Nuxt plugin

```
const axios = require('axios')
module.exports = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'domain.nl/path/to/my/api'
})
```

You can find more info in the comments below

Comment: Im a using `"axios": "^0.18.0"`

Comment: So when you implement this there is no (get)request send to the url?

Comment: No, it doesn't, I have copied your same line of code and I'm using the same axios version, have you tried to use axios.create instead?

Comment: const axios = require('axios')

module.exports = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://domain.nl/path/to/my/api'
})

Comment: Thanks for this heads up! I my config (`axios({`) i have added .create (`axios.create({`) and that did the trick. Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 2):

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Axios from "axios";


Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;

Axios.defaults.headers.common = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
Axios.defaults.baseURL = (process.env.API_PATH !== 'production') ? 'http://localhost:8000/api/' : '';
```

Ensure baseURL not baseUrl

Comment: Thanks saved me some hours