# Axios baseURL sends unintended get request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Defining `axios.defaults.baseURL = baseUrl;` sends strange get request immediately after my Vue app is initialized. Would be grateful for your help!

Images of code and Network requests are below:

Tried to use [Setting baseUrl for Axios in Vue js sends out request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359758/setting-baseurl-for-axios-in-vue-js-sends-out-request)

But that didn't work for me

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const baseUrl = 'http://imfood-core.local';

axios.defaults.baseURL = baseUrl;

axios.interceptors.request.use(function (request) {
  if(request.url !== `/api/login_check`){
    request.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
  }
  return request;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);

});

axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = baseUrl;
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  if(error.response && error.response.status == 401 && error.config.url !== `${baseUrl}/api/login_check`){
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      window.location.reload();
      return Promise.reject(error);
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export default axios;



[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E9dD.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnBST.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sy5z.png
```

Comment: Instead of posting images of the code, paste a representative portion into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new axios instance, then provide it to your files, just importing this file.

```
import axios from 'axios'

const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://imfood-core.local'
})

client.interceptors.request.use(function (request) {
  if(request.url !== `/api/login_check`){
    request.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
  }
  return request;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);

});

...

export default client
```

Comment: Yeah :) That worked! Problem was in axios default import, after instance creation the problem disappeared. Thanks